# How do I use the Consolas font in the Windows XP command prompt?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, fonts

How? I can see only two options in the properties dialog: "Lucida Console" and "Raster Fonts". Is there any way to switch to Consolas (short of replacing the Lucida TTF file with the Consolas TTF file)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scott Hanselman had a post on exactly that topic [Using Consolas as Windows Console Font](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingConsolasAsTheWindowsConsoleFont.aspx). Also [here](http://blog.wolffmyren.com/2008/09/15/consolas-as-cmdexe-windows-console-font/).

[image]

Comment: For those too lazy to click: Fire up regedit and add a REG_SZ value to `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/Console/TrueTypeFont` with the name `00` and the value `Consolas`. Then reboot.